# Yii : continue action after login

Tags: php, yii

I have a page that contains a form in my Yii app.

I want to allow all users to view this form, but on submission of the form, if the user is not logged in - I want to redirect him to the login page. After the user logs in, I want to continue the original form submission.

For example in this page :
http://www.yiiframework.com/demos/blog/index.php/post/13/sadfasdfasdf#comments
When the user clicks on "submit" he will be redirected to the login page and after login his comment will be submitted has a logged in user.

How should I do that?

---

The solution I used :

1. I followed this info to set the return URL : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/43/adding-login-form-to-each-page/
2. Before sending the guest to the login page, I save the POST info in session.
   Than when the user gets redirected to the original page, I check if the session contains the original POST info and if it does - I save it with the new user id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the original POST variables in session if the user isn't logged in. Otherwise, event if you use the `returnUrl` as other folks are suggesting, you will have lost the comment originally submitted.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
```

This will redirect on a page that has requested user for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

by using url referrer you can do this stuff

```
$returnUrl = Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer;
```

Comment: Can you explain where I should use it? The value of Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer in actionLogin is mydomain.com/user/login so I can't use it to do a redirect at the end of actionLogin